# react native fetch fails randomly on IOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

Same fetch code works all good in android. On IOS most of the time works, but it also does thro network request failed error.

The case is so, the app redirects to some other app for some process to complete which in this case I would say is in background mode and once the process complete it redirects back to app in foreground mode, so than right at this point it makes an http request call a fetch call.

**Error:** Network request failed

**Expected Results**
I would expect the same request to go through on both platforms as per usual.

Code example:

```
const login = async (authData) => {
  console.log('fetching...');
  //Setting up the request
  //Select apropriate port 8515 | 8516
  const port = handlePortSelection(authData.username);
  const url = `http:\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:${port}/api/Auth/LoginUser`;

  const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'};

  const body = JSON.stringify(authData);

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: body
  };

  try {
    //Call API
    const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);

    const data = await response.json();

    setUserData(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Any idea what is it causing this random behaviour on ios usually tested on ios 13 and 14.

**React native version:** 0.61.5

Comment: How are you testing it? On an actual iPhone? In an emulator?

Comment: actual iphone mostly, also simulator. same thing!

Comment: They are not the same thing!